# AES Encrypt in groovy, decrypt in c#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, groovy

I need to encrypt a small string of text using a pre-shared key using Groovy and AES.

The system on the other side needs to decrypt using C# and cannot be changed (at all). It is using the class AesManaged with the default settings and is using `ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor()` to decrypt. It uses a BlockSize of 128, KeySize of 256, CBC mode, and padding of PKCS7.

The question is, assuming the key and initialization vector are the same on both sides, can anyone see why this wouldn't be able to be decrypted on the c# side? Both sides are just decoding the key from Base64 and have a common shared key storage location.

It is encrypted successfully.

```
def cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
def key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.decodeBase64(), 0, 32, "AES")
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv))
vars.put('encryptedMessage', cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8")).encodeBase64() as String)
vars.put('iv', iv.encodeBase64() as String)
```

The decryption side looks like this:

```
AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
aes.Key = (code i'm not willing to share)
aes.IV = (code i'm not willing to share)
using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(payload))
    {
      using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
      {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream) cryptoStream))
          return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether the Groovy encryption code corresponds to the C# decryption code can only be answered reliably (i.e. without guessing) if you post the C# decryption code. Additionally you should post non-productive test data for `secret`, `message`, `encryptedMessage` and `iv`.

Comment: I've added the decryption side to the question. I'm aware that it will depend on the operating system it is being run on and its registry settings as to the exact settings being used. However for the example, I'm testing it against a controlled test environment where I know the parameters are what I have put in my question.

Comment: *...code i'm not willing to share...* Well, you shouldn't share productive test data, but **non-productive** test data (since not everyone has a running Groovy and C# environment). In your code, the encoding of key, IV and ciphertext is possibly inconsistent ("possibly" because it is not clear from the C# code what encoding your data has). In any case, I cannot reproduce the problem on my maschine (i.e. decryption works if I Base64 decode the data in the C# code)!

Comment: Interesting, thankyou for trying.

Comment: I did understand what you were asking around non-production data, however this isn't possible.

Comment: provide some test data instead of placeholders

Comment: also make your code snippets working.\

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the encryption, which was perfectly compatible. Unfortunately I had not realised that the message formatting was different between the server and client.